# Is there a way to render application.scss to a css string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to inline some css for a template (for html to img, not for email) with the Roadie gem which requires a css string. I want to convert my application.scss file into a string but I can't find a reliable way to do so. Currenty I'm just copying it from the browser but I'd like to do it programatically.

What i've tried is:

```
str = File.read("app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss")
se = Sass::Engine.new(str, :syntax => :scss)
se.render
```

This gives me issues with sass loaded by gems like Bootstrap sprockets:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-variables
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Please post your `application.scss` but it looks like that file is probably trying to load something like `@import bootstrap-variables` `Sass::Engine` won't know if the `bootstrap-variables.scss` files are not in the same directory as `application.scss` although rails might if you're using a rails bootstrap-sass gem for example.

Make sure your `@import` files have valid sass and are named correctly and are in the same directory as `application.scss` The same for other files which might be imported in `application.scss`.

Then you should be able to just do:

```
css = Sass::Engine.for_file('application.scss', {}).render
```

If you are trying to do this inside rails, then it's likely you've loaded bootstrap via a gem and rails will handle precompilation of assets and know where to look for the imports.  Rather than have to try to figure out where everything lives for your purpose, it might then be easier to just run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` then you can do something like this:

```
filename = Dir.entries('public/assets/').find{|f| f.match(/application-\w+.css$/)}
css = Sass::Engine.for_file(filename, {}).render
#css is the flat css compiled from the rails precompile
```

But since you already precompiled you can just do

```
css = 
File.read(
  Dir.entries('public/assets/').find do |filename|
    filename.match(/application-\w+.css$/)
  end
)
```

The magic `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` will generate a flat css file with a name like `application-a30bb6a9753337386468559f6f44286d58d74f88ddc710b5d5832a67b576d16a.css`

So we use a regex in the above to pattern match the file name.

Comment: The first three imports are `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";` `@import "bootstrap-variables";` `@import "bootstrap";` These imports are handled by rails, so there's no way to put them into the same dir. Is there some way to have rails handle the conversion? My current work around is to make a separate scss file with the bootstrap code injected directly, though this means there are two files that need to be manually kept in sync.

Comment: see my updated answer.  You should be able to invoke precompile if you need to.  For rails, precompile normally gets done before/during deployments to production.

Comment: it sounds like your trying to do what `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` already does for you? What do you mean by "two files that need to be manually kept in sync" ?